# Calculation between row_value at sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following table.

```
| col_num | row_num  | value     |
|---------|----------|-----------|
| 1       | 3        | 5(value1) |
| 2       | 4        | 7(value2) |
| 5       | 1        | 8(value3) |
```

Now I want to conduct `(value2) / (sqrt(value1)*sqrt(value2))` by querying in sqlite3.

Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: How do you know which value is which?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
select col_num, row_num,
value/((select sqrt(value) from tbl where row_num = 3) * sqrt(value)) as newValue
from tbl where row_num = 4;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. nice idea!!

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear how you know what is `value1`, `value2`, and `value3`.  You can use conditional aggregation.  If you were to use `row_num`, then it would look like:

```
select (max(case when row_number = 4 then value end) /
        sqrt(max(case when row_nunmber = 3 then value end) *
             max(case when row_nunmber = 1 then value end)
            )
       )
from t;
```

EDIT:

If the `valueX` is actually part of the value itself:

```
select max(case when value like '%(value2)' then substring_index(value, '(', 1) + 0 end) /
            sqrt(max(case when '%(value1)' then substring_index(value, '(', 1) + 0 end) *
                 max(case when '%(value2)' then substring_index(value, '(', 1) + 0 end)
                )
           )
from t;
```

Comment: If you see the 'value' column, there are value1, value2, value3 inside parenthesis. Sorry for confusing expression.